What does "Yes" mean as a reply to a statement? Do we still use it?
From Pride and Prejudice:

D: Are you staying at Lambton? E: Yes. At the Rose and Crown. D: Yes.

From the same scene:

E: I'm very fond of walking. D: Yes.

What does it mean?
It's English from 200 years ago, so my another question would be is this still used. I think I heard such an odd yes in an Australian TV show.

Is this the book, a movie, or TV show? If either of the last two, which version?

They weren't making movies or TV shows 200 years ago; the dialog will be 'modernised'.

'Yes' on its own, in response to a statement (not a question) usually means something like 'OK', 'I understand', or 'I agree', depending on what was said. And, yes, it is used today.

"Yes" can just reinforce what somebody said even if it is a statement. [My other question, not another].

What @MichaelHarvey said. Sometimes, "Yes" just means "I heard you",  "Roger", "Check"

It is still used.  It answers the question in the affirmative:

Are you staying at Lambton?
Yes

"Yes" means "I am staying at Lambton."
It can also mean "I understand" or "I have heard you", or "I concur".  Finally it can mean "I understand, but tell me more." or "Really?"
So in the dialogue "at the Rose and Crown"/ "Yes",  it means that the interviewer understands the speaker.
It seems likely (from infering the context) that "I'm very fond of walking"/"Yes?"  (note the question mark to show intonation) means "Really?" or "Is that so?" or "Please tell me more!"
These are all social cues. The "meaning" is not so important. What is important is the shared feeling that is created.
